# I'm using browsermobproxy in selenium (Python) and I'm getting an error when doing server.start()

Tags: python, selenium, browsermob-proxy

First, I get this error:

`browsermobproxy.exceptions.ProxyServerError: The Browsermob-Proxy server process failed to start. Check <_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:\\Users\\jackg\\Desktop\\Python Code\\DataCampSolver\\server.log' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>for a helpful error message.`

Then when I check server.log I get this error:

`'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I have the browsermob-proxy file installed

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

server = Server("bin/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

server.stop()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Try using the full path. `Server(r"C:\Path\To\bmp\bin\browsermob-proxy")`

Comment: Didn't work, same issue :(